# Can't get menu to open properly after clicking on hamburger icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't get a fiddle working but I have the issue live [here](http://darrenbachan.com/).

When I click on the icon I get the menu to show for a brief second and then it disappears again. I thought with the javascript I have was saying that if I click on it, it'll stay open until you click on it again to close.

**HTML**

```
<div class="hamburger hamburger--spin" tabindex="0"
     aria-label="Menu" role="button" aria-controls="navigation">
   <div class="hamburger-box">
      <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<nav id="menu">Content</nav>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".hamburger").click(function() { 
    $("#menu").fadeIn("fast");
});
$(".hamburger").click(function() { 
    $("#menu").fadeOut("fast");
});

var $hamburger = $(".hamburger");
$hamburger.on("click", function(e) {
    $hamburger.toggleClass("is-active");
    // Do something else, like open/close menu
});
```

I have `display:none;` on `#menu` and when I click on the `.hamburger` it gives it `display:block;` I'm not sure what exactly is doing that. Also is there a way to combine this js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have binded two times the `click` event, the first one tries to show the element and then the second one tries to hide it while it's still showing, thus showing it always. Try this code

```js
$(function() {
  $(".hamburger").click(function() {
    if ($("#menu").is(":hidden"))
      $("#menu").fadeIn("fast");
    else
      $("#menu").fadeOut("fast");
  });

  var $hamburger = $(".hamburger");
  $hamburger.on("click", function(e) {
    $hamburger.toggleClass("is-active");
    // Do something else, like open/close menu
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hamburger hamburger--spin" tabindex="0" aria-label="Menu" role="button" aria-controls="navigation">
  <div class="hamburger-box">
    <div class="hamburger-inner">INner</div>
  </div>
</div>

<nav id="menu">Content</nav>
```

Comment: Amazing, this worked! So I'm trying to understand the solution. My javascript knowledge is lacking. So because #menu is display:none; it becomes :hidden for the js to acknowledge that?

Comment: Take into account that `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` are immediate animations that last a number of ms, though jQuery animations can be [queued](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) one after another

Comment: Meaning I could delay it if I wanted to use the original code so that it does actually open?

Comment: Rather than delay, queue them. To delay them you can use `setTimeout` javascript function